# Dockerfile with Go plugins

Tags: docker, go, plugins, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which creates an image for our project. Setting up everything properly, but I'm looking for the best way I can build my container image, because we have more plugins which determine the behaviour of our project.

So the case, there is the main binary and there is ~10 plugin and I can use 1 or more for my Go binary. Currently these plugins mostly in the same repository as the main project, but in the future there will be other plugins in different repositories.

I'm looking for the best way to have Docker image building mechanism where I can have these plugins.

What I have right now:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base

# Create appuser.
RUN adduser -D -g '' project-user

WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/bitbucket.org/company/project
COPY . .

RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -s" -o /go/bin/project

# Minimal version of image
FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/project /go/bin/project

USER project-user
EXPOSE 7676

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/project"]
```

This doesn't have the plugins, so it won't start properly because the binary requires at least one plugin, but there is the `plugins` flag waits for plugins like `plugin.so` or `plugin1.so;plugin2.so;..`.

As I told you there is multiple plugins, and right now we have RPM builders and these builds the binary and all plugins separately, and we do `yum install project plugin1 plugin2` and in the config file (because the flags could read from config as well) we add the plugins.

We want to change to **Kubernetes** so this is why I'm looking for this solution in Dockerfile.

Comment: Create independent Dockerfiles that build FROM the base image you currently have. Let each of those files ADD or COPY a particular combination of plugins you are interested in.

Comment: That's really how you always do it if you think about it. You can consider, say, an official RedHat image the base image, and each package a plugin. Then you build your desired image by stacking Dockerfiles that each add one or more packages.

Comment: That make sense. Can you write it as an answer and I can accept it, because this is the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all i see some problems with your `Dockerfile`, i can only address those since i don't fully understand your 'plugins' issues.

1. It's a bad idea to copy `/etc/passwd` like that, you could get away with this approach but you would have to copy all relevant files for users and groups, `cp /etc/{passwd,shadow,group,gshadow}` for example, and then be sure to fix permissions. You are safer just creating the user only in the final image, you're not even using it in the builder, and the context size is negligible if that is what you're aiming for by running the `adduser` in the builder.
2. If your `go` program calls `C` code then you will need to base your final image on something other than `scratch` because it does not have the required libraries. You need a base image with some variant of `libc`, the most light weight is `musl` and you get that with the `alpine` images. If your `go` program does not call any `C` code then you can use the `CGO_ENABLED=0` flag during `go build` and then your built binary program won't depend on anything, thus you can use the `scratch` or `busybox` base images. You can find more info on `cgo` [here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will have them.